# How to create a sap.m.Table with responsive column width?

Tags: sapui5

I want to have a `sap.m.Table` with responsive column width. I know that there are `sap.ui.layout` controls that allow - together with the `span` property - to specify width dependent on the window size. For example:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
  <layoutData>
    <layout:GridData xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" span="L7 M5 S12" />
  </layoutData>
<!-- ... -->
```

The above code snippet specifies that an element takes 7/12 of the available space on large screens, 5/12 on medium size screens and the whole available space on small screens. So how can I combine those elements to get a table with responsive column width?

For example in the following table, how can I give column c1 the `span="L8 M6 S12"` and the column c2 `span="L4 M6 S0"`? The label in the column header shall be aligned correspondingly!

```xml
<Table xmlns="sap.m">
  <columns>
    <Column id="c1">
      <Label text="My Column 1" />
    </Column>
    <Column id="c2">
      <Label text="My Column 2" />
    </Column>
  </columns>
  <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle">
    <ObjectListItem title="My Object 1" />
    <ObjectListItem title="My Object 2" />
  </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

I've searched for "ResponsiveFlowLayout" but the results were not helpful.